# working with Generics to specify the sub class type?

Tags: java, generics

I Have below the constructor and private paramter.

```
private Class class;
public SomeRequest(subClass_of_SomeClass.java){
        this.class=subClass_of_above_parameter;
    }
```

Now the constructor should not accept any class type. **It has to accept the class type which is a sub class of SomeClass.java.**

How can i write a generic parameter?

```
private Class<SomeClass> class;
```

Is above declaration correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like:

```
private class Class<T extends SomeClass> { ... }
```

or

```
private class Class<? extends SomeClass> { ... }
```

(editted for the sake of correctness, in case someone would need to compile it ;))

Comment: Kamil, my requirement is it should accept only SomeClass sub classes and not SomeClass.

Comment: so I don't think that it's syntactically possible, you could only chnage classes, so that there is one more class like `class Extended extends SomeClass`, and all current subclasses should extend this added one - then you could do `private Class<? extends ExtendedSomeClass> class;`

Comment: Kamil, wt is the difference between above two lines and which one is recommended?

Comment: you use T only when you declare generic type on the class

Comment: `private Class<T extends SomeClass> class;` is not valid Java syntax

Comment: of course it is, I copy-pasted from OP, I just wanted to show the idea which was apparently understood as seen from "correct answer" flag, but thanks for downvoting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Best way of doing it will be the way @Kamil explained but if you specifically want to use subclasses then Declare SomeClass as abstract or declare it as Interface.